# Mplayer2 stuck when I press XF86Audio keys

Tags: arch-linux, mplayer, kwin

When mplayer2 got focused, if I press XF86 audio keys, e.g. volume up, it gets stuck for one second then continues to play the video.

If mplayer is not focused, that won't happen.

Is there any way to prevent that behavior?

Running `MPlayer2 UNKNOWN (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team`, Arch Linux, Kwin + RazorQt desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution, but works

Open up `libvo/x11_common.c`, find these lines:

```
#ifdef XF86XK_AudioPause
    {XF86XK_MenuKB, KEY_MENU},
    {XF86XK_AudioPlay, KEY_PLAY}, {XF86XK_AudioPause, KEY_PAUSE}, {XF86XK_AudioStop, KEY_STOP},
    {XF86XK_AudioPrev, KEY_PREV}, {XF86XK_AudioNext, KEY_NEXT},
    {XF86XK_AudioMute, KEY_MUTE}, {XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume, KEY_VOLUME_DOWN}, {XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume, KEY_VOLUME_UP},
#endif
```

And remove these

`{XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume, KEY_VOLUME_DOWN}, {XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume, KEY_VOLUME_UP},`

Re-compile it and it would no longer stuck.